# SQL UNIR 3 TABLA PERO SE ME ROMPE

Tags: sql

TENGO ESTA CONASULTA QUE ME TRAE ESTE RESULTADO
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PERO CUANDO INTENGO AGREGAR OTRA TABLA QUE RELACIONA LA FILA OP SE ROMPE
YA INTENTE HACER COMO UNA SUB CONSULTA, QUE SOLO BUSQUE EL RESULTADO
PERO NO ME DEJA QUERIA SABER SI HAY AGUNA SOLUCION.
GRACIAS....

Comment: puedes colocar algún ejemplo verificable o mejorar tu pregunta? la verdad que no se entiende ni se ve el problema.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿Qué significa que se rompe? ¿Tienes un error? ¿cuál? ¿No te trae la información que esperas? por favor acláralo editando tu pregunta.